# how do i show formula result if any two selected cell has value in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a scenario where i have two cell for input Data E24 and I24 and one cell for calculation k24. What i want is if there is value in any of those input cell the calculation should show in the formula cell K24 if input cell E24 and I24 both are empty then keep the formula cell K24 blank.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> > if there is value in any of those input cell the calculation should show in the formula cell K24

Can you let us know What calculation is done in cell K24?

If you do an addition calculation, please try the formula `=IF(AND(E24="",I24=""),"",E24+I24)` to have a check.